# Ensure nodes are not being added to keras graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Dynamically adding nodes to a TF graph will make it execute remarkably slow.

I have a Keras model, with TF backend, which I'm currently debugging. The architecture is pretty complex with a lot of custom layers, so I wanted to ensure nodes aren't being added after the graph is compiled. In the past I've used `sess.graph.finalize()` as an assert; however, this doesn't seem to work for a Keras model. The simple example below will fail at this check with `RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.`

```
import keras
import numpy as np

x = y = np.linspace(0,10)

X = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,))
_Y = keras.layers.Dense(1)(X)
Y = keras.models.Model(X, _Y)

Y.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='sgd')
sess = keras.backend.get_session()
sess.graph.finalize() 
Y.fit(x, y, epochs=5)
```

What is the proper way to perform this check in Keras?